# AX Report Mainaccount Opening Balance Dataset

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, axapta, x++

We have to develop some features for the report "LedgerAccountStatementPerCurrency" (AX 2012).

One of the Features is, to show for each mainaccount in the report the opening balance (transaction Currency).

I wrote a Stored Procedure a long time ago on the SQL Server which gives me this as return value. The parameters are mainaccountid, datefrom and dateto.

My question is if it is possible to use this Stored Procedure? 
The Report depence on the class "LedgerAccountStatementPerCurrencyDP", can i implement, that for each mainaccount the system gives to the report, i call my Stored Procedure an give the balance in another field back?

What's the way in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this report you have this info. Check `LedgerAccountStatementPerCurrencyDP` class `processReport` method. Here after `while (queryRun.next())` you can see this standard code to calculate **opening balance**.

In the next code find this label `//Here OpeningBalance`

***Here the code***

```
...
...
...
queryRun = new QueryRun(query);
while (queryRun.next())
{
    generalJournalAccountEntry = queryRun.get(tableNum(GeneralJournalAccountEntry)) as GeneralJournalAccountEntry;
    generalJournalEntry = queryRun.get(tableNum(GeneralJournalEntry)) as GeneralJournalEntry;
    fiscalCalendarPeriod = queryRun.get(tableNum(FiscalCalendarPeriod)) as FiscalCalendarPeriod;
    dimAttrValueCombo = queryRun.get(tableNum(DimensionAttributeValueCombination)) as DimensionAttributeValueCombination;

    if (dimAttrValueCombo.MainAccount != prevMainAccount)
    {
        mainAccount = MainAccount::find(dimAttrValueCombo.MainAccount);
        localizedName = mainAccount.localizedName();
    }

    ledgerAccountStatementPerCurrencyTmp.clear();
    ledgerAccountStatementPerCurrencyTmp.MainAccountId = mainAccount.MainAccountId;
    ledgerAccountStatementPerCurrencyTmp.AccountName = localizedName;

    if (dimAttrValueCombo.MainAccount != prevMainAccount)
    {
        if (mainAccount && ledgerBalanceOpening)
        {
        //Here OpeningBalance
            ledgerBalanceOpening.calculateBalance(mainAccount);
            openingBalance = ledgerBalanceOpening.getAccountingCurrencyBalance();
        //Here OpeningBalance END
        }
        else
        {
            openingBalance = 0;
        }

        ledgerAccountStatementPerCurrencyTmp.OpeningBalance = openingBalance;
        ledgerAccountStatementPerCurrencyTmp.insert();

        prevMainAccount = dimAttrValueCombo.MainAccount;
    }
...
...
...
```

Comment: ok and how can i add a new field that is given to the Report for example "OpeningBalanceTransaction"? in this code section i have all things i need for my stored procedure(dateFrom, dateTo, mainaccountID) so i can call it here and fill the new added field "OpeningBalanceTransaction" or?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. To perform that you must create a new field in `LedgerAccountStatementPerCurrencyTmp` table. Add code for this new field in `ProcessReport` method. Then in **Visual Studio** refresh the datasource `LedgerAccountStatementPerCurrencyDS` to appear your new field, then in layout add your new field.

Comment: ok i will try it, post my result and mark your answer as best ;)